# Installing MySQL on CentOS 6 VM (Vagrant) with bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, centos, vagrant

I'm using this script to install and create database, and edit users and permissions:

```
sudo yum install mysql-server mysql-client -y

MYSQL_NAME="databasename"
MYSQL_USER="newuser"
MYSQL_PASS="12341234"
MYSQL_ROOTPWD=`openssl rand -base64 12`
MYSQL_TMPFILE=`mktemp --suffix=.sql`

echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$MYSQL_ROOTPWD') WHERE User='root';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "DROP DATABASE test;" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "CREATE DATABASE $MYSQL_NAME CHARACTER SET 'utf8';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "GRANT ALL ON $MYSQL_NAME.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASS';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "GRANT ALL ON test_$MYSQL_NAME.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASS';" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE

cat $MYSQL_TMPFILE | mysql -u root
rm $MYSQL_TMPFILE
```

Then when I run the VM and try to access the database, I cannot access without any user, it sais root password and newuser password doesn't fit. I save both password to a file after the script finished. Any help here to know where is the problem with the mysql ??

Some times, when I destroy the VM and try again, the result comes with an error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)

I'm running on Ubuntu 13 and the VM is CentOS 6

Comment: A trivial question: are you sure mysql daemon is running when you launch the script?

Comment: Sure I didn't write the full script because is big, and there is a lot of things not related with this. But after mysql installation, I call the process mysql to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems was with:

```
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | tee -a $MYSQL_TMPFILE
```

The tmp file the script was creating has some errors for the MySQL syntax. If I write the tmp file or execute the commands inside the mysql console, MySQL run perfectly